# What does "one more step from the future" mean?

Tags: meaning, grammar, semantics

I'm not sure it's a correct English sentence.

Can it be interpreted as "bringing something back from the future and advancing the present"?

Maybe it would be better to use "one more step to the future" to convey a similar message?

Comment: I heard this sentence from someone trying to describe an innovative technology that can help humans to advance to the future.

Comment: Source: a person I met today. Context: he was talking about an AI software.

Comment: Was this a native speaker? Are you sure it wasn't _away from_?

Comment: Not a native speaker. Yes I'm completely sure it was as I wrote here.

Comment: It isn't a correct English sentence, and it can't be interpreted that way. You are right in that "one more step to the future" would be clear and understood by all. (That someone programming AI is trying to tell others what he is doing and it doesn't make sense is a little scary.)

Comment: ...or maybe _"towards_ the future". i.e. the glass is half  full, or..."

Comment: It sounds a bit like the 20th century discovery of the Terminator hand that started the development that led to the Terminators in the Terminator movie. That is a development without a start point.